# Three.js same shader with multiple objects different parameters

Tags: javascript, three.js, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I'm working with three.js and trying to write a shader to render many spheres with all of the same attributes except their radii. The radii are varying in real time and I'm not sure what the most efficient way to change the radii of the individual spheres.

Here is what I have so far to test. It seems that my uniform variable `radius` doesn't actually affect the radius of the sphere at all.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Test Sphere</title>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r71/three.min.js"></script>
<script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexShader">
    /**
     * Multiply each vertex by the
     * model-view matrix and the
     * projection matrix (both provided
     * by Three.js) to get a final
     * vertex position
     */
     uniform float radius;

    void main() {
      gl_Position = radius * projectionMatrix *
                    modelViewMatrix *
                    vec4(position,1.0);
    }

</script>

<script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="fragmentShader">
    /**
     * Set the colour to a lovely pink.
     * Note that the color is a 4D Float
     * Vector, R,G,B and A and each part
     * runs from 0.0 to 1.0
     */
    void main() {
      gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,  // R
                          0.0,  // G
                          1.0,  // B
                          1.0); // A
    }

</script>

<script>
var light;
var material;
var scene, camera;

var puthere = document.getElementById("test");
container = document.createElement( 'div' );
puthere.appendChild( container );

scene = new THREE.Scene();
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
camera.position.z = 300;
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight )
container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var uniforms = {
    radius: { type: "f", value: 10.0 }
};

material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
    uniforms: uniforms,
    vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertexShader' ).textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent
} );

var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 1, 32, 32 );
sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
// material.needsUpdate = true;
scene.add( sphere );
scene.add( camera );
renderer.render( scene, camera );
setInterval( function() {
    console.log( "here" );
    sphere.material.uniforms.radius.value += 10;
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}, 100);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post any code that you have written so far and describe any actual issues you may be having with this.

Comment: obviously you need new instance of material. if the shader source does not change, it should not cost much.

Comment: I just edited my question to include the test code I am using. Please let me know if I should include anything else